# How can i use RabbitMQ for sending mobile push notifications?

Tags: mobile, push-notification, rabbitmq

**Scope:**

I have an app that i am starting to build that has the "subscriber/publisher" situation on it's core.

For those who don't know, the idea behind this schema is that:

1) Someone creates a "Topic"

2) Endpoints subscribe to a "Topic"

3) Any message published to a certain "Topic" is pushed to the subscribers of said "Topic"

**Considerations:**

I am going to use Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android as the framework to build this mobile app (so that it can be crossplatform from the begining).

**RabbitMQ:**

The [RabbitMQ](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rabbitmq.com%2F&ei=uc8PU9aYLMbMkQfMloH4DQ&usg=AFQjCNGDosbIEgmvo7ybtwDm3q37XqGfbA&sig2=XTkCTEJv8j9UQgehvic62w&bvm=bv.61965928,d.eW0) service is built on top of the AMQP pattern which solves my entire problem of modeling the "Topic/Subscriber/Publisher" problem.

**The Problem:**

Now that I have the problem modeled via the RabbitMQ framework, I need those "Messages" that are "pushed" to each endpoint (mobile device) to actually be a "Push Notification" instead of the standard message that will arrive to that device.

How can I model my solution to accomplish that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well asked, but did you managed to achieve this ?

Comment: @GrecoJonathan I did not, but knowing the problem / frameworks way better now I figure that all you need to do is to receive the messages on the device as a regular "Queue Message" from RabbitMQ, and manually create / fire up the notification through your app. Essentially something that parses the message, manually creates the Android notification object and displays it (something like: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: Hello @MarcelloGrechiLins. Did you solve this? If so please can you share your answer here. I am trying to implement something similar but with flutter.

Comment: @cdaiga Seeing a post of mine from 6 years sure is cool ! I was an intern back then lol!
To answer your question: What you need is that the "Consumer" of each message, parses each message in the queue (that should contain information about targets), and use the applicable SDK to send push notifications (Google's, Apple's etc). Alternatively, you can use a service such as AWS pinpoint : https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/push-notification-services/  to send said notifications, and use SNS as the Pub/Sub, or SQS as the message queue.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ can't send out the push notification itself.

For each message consumed from the a RabbitMQ queue, the "Consumer" service needs to invoke whatever push notification backend/API you are using (e.g. Firebase, AWS, etc.) using their SDK.